# How to capture list data into data frame

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, list, dataframe

I have below code to capture data from two different tables , compare both the results and get the output.

```
EmplTbl = cur.execute("select A , B , C from EmployeeTable where EmplName in ('A','B')") 
emp_entries = set(cur)

DeptTbl = cur.execute("select A , B , C from DeptTable") 
dept_entries = set(cur) 

print(emp_entries.difference(dept_entries))
```

Below is the output i am receiving

```
Output: 

{(1, A, X),(2, B, Y),(3, B, Y)}
```

When i am trying to assign it to dataframe i am getting " 'dict' object has no attribute 'append' "
How can i assign above "Data" into proper dataframe  with Columns A,B,C or any other way .

Expected Output:

```
 A, B, C     
 1, A, X
 2, B, Y
 3, B, Y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass sets to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = {(1, 'A', 'X'),(2, 'B', 'Y'),(3, 'B', 'Y')}

cols = ['A','B','C']
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=cols)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  2  B  Y
1  1  A  X
2  3  B  Y
```

If need sorting by first values:

```
a = {(1, 'A', 'X'),(2, 'B', 'Y'),(3, 'B', 'Y')}

L  = sorted(list(a), key=lambda tup: tup[0])
cols = ['A','B','C']
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=cols)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  A  X
1  2  B  Y
2  3  B  Y
```

For remove index values if write to `csv` use:

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But can i exclude index and also is there any possibility can i pass columns names through a variable . Instead of columns=['A','B','C'])  , can i do something like this columns=[Variable] ?

Comment: @ can i ask one more doubt please ?

Comment: @Arya - Sure, no problem.

Comment: Instead of -- cur.execute("select A , B , C from DeptTable")  -- , instead of specifying the column names A,B,C in query , how can i pass column names also  with a variable like ---  cur.execute("select $Variable from DeptTable")

Comment: @Arya - use `cur.execute("select {} from DeptTable".format(Variable))`